# Can I append a list to a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list of lists which contain different values and different lengths.

I want my code to iterate the "big list", and if an "item-list" (a sub-list in the big list) follows a condition (for example, `len(list[i] > 1`), I want to add this "item-list" to a *new* big list, so at the end, I will get a new list of lists (which all follow the condition).

The `append()` methoddoesn't work when I want to append a whole list.
Do you have any suggestion, how should I do it?

Comment: We are not very good at making sense of plain text questions. Do show some code and expected output

Comment: Why wouldn't append work? You can always add an item to an existing list, even if it is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it would be

```
new_big_list = [x for x in big_list if condition(x)]
```

but the loop with `.append()` should work if you start with an empty list